# using a textbox value as string in Access

Tags: string, ms-access, textbox, vba, report

I have a table that feeds several reports. For each customer, for example, I have a different report with his own logo, etc, but all these reports gets their data from one table. Each report has a different name which is attached to the customer name in a different column.
I have then a form where I select the customer and the respective report name comes up in a textbox.
I want to open each individual report with a command button using the following command:
DoCmd.OpenReport " REPORT_NAME ", acViewPreview

"REPORT_NAME" has to be replaced with the string value from the textbox for each individual customer from the opening form.

What command should I use to solve this?

I hope this is not too confusing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I'm missing something, but you can simply do

```
DoCmd.OpenReport Me!theTextboxWithReportName, acViewPreview
```

or a little more elaborate

```
Dim strReport As String
strReport = Nz(Me!theTextboxWithReportName, "")
If strReport <> "" Then
    DoCmd.OpenReport strReport, acViewPreview
End If
```

Comment: Dear Andre,

Thank you very much for your reply. The first simple line solves my problem very elegant, I wasn't sure how to use the "Me" command. I kept using Me.textbox instead of Me!textbox.

Problem solved. Thank you very much.